# C# .NET How i can add code editor C# to my website?

Tags: c#, .net

How i can add code editor C#,which will compile the code in live
I tried something with Ace, but nothing so far
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to propose an input to user. They had C# code (no matter what) and your server executes it.
If yes, take a look at [that](https://www.codemag.com/Article/0211081/Dynamically-Executing-Code-in-.NET).
It creates a project and build it in memory before executing it.
Be careful cause if you execute the code no matter what it will be a security breach into your server. For example, someone could execute a code which will download a file onto your server and open a backdoor to it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think it will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Check this site:
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/try-dotnet
This is embeddable .Net compiler which you could use without any preparations and setups